# Display an array of objects in Reactjs

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, object

I am new to ReactJS and web dev in general, I am trying to render a local json file to my EmojiList component.

I am not sure what's wrong with my code. I am using typescript as well.

Can anyone please have a look? Thanks in advance.

EmojiList.tsx file:

```
const json = require('../../emojisDb/emojis.json');

const EmojiList = (props: any) => {
  const [emojis, setEmojis] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const newObj: any = {};
    const jsonString = JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, json));
    Object.keys(jsonString).map((categ: any, emoji: any) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <div key={categ}>{categ}</div>
          <ul>
            {emojis.map((emoji: any) => (
              <li key={emoji.id}>{emoji}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
      console.log(emoji);
    });
    setEmojis(newObj);
    console.log(newObj);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={classes.iconsTabWrapper}>
      <div className={emojiClasses.currentEmojiList}>
        <div className={emojiClasses.emojiWrapper}>
          <div className={emojiClasses.emojiRow}>{emojis}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default EmojiList;
```

This is how my json file looks

```
{
  "smileys": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "emoji": "",
      "description": "grinning face",
      "tags": ["smile", "happy"]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "emoji": "",
      "description": "grinning face with big eyes",
      "tags": ["happy", "joy", "haha"]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "emoji": "",
      "description": "grinning face with smiling eyes",
      "tags": ["happy", "joy", "laugh", "pleased"]
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "emoji": "",
      "description": "beaming face with smiling eyes",
      "tags": ["teeth"]
    }
]
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? Ask it

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't set value for `newObj`. Just update like this in `useEffect`

```
const newObj = Object.keys(jsonString).map((categ: any, emoji: any) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div key={categ}>{categ}</div>
      <ul>
        {emojis.map((emoji: any) => (
          <li key={emoji.id}>{emoji}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
});

setEmojis(newObj);
```